# Radare2 cannot open bin for writing

Tags: disassembly, radare2

Im on Kali and im using Radare2 but it says

```
r2 -d bin
Killing child process 16151 due to an error
Killing child process 16152 due to an error
[w] Cannot open 'dbg://./bin' for writing.
```

I tried `chmod +x bin` and I still get the same result, can someone help me, im still a beginnner

Comment: Does it work when you debug `bin` in `gdb`?

Comment: Since the error message is related to writing (instead of execution, which is what the problem usually is) have you tried adding write permissions to the bin file and running the above command again?

Comment: What's a version of r2 you're having on your system?